# Sharepoint uploaded file name was changed by server event. How to retrieve it?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I'm uploading file to Sharepoint server using this code:

```
ClientOM.File uploadFile = null;
try {

    string fileRef = serverRelativeURL + msg.Message.FileName;
    FileCreationInformation fileCreationInformation = new FileCreationInformation() {
        Content = msg.Content,
        Url = fileRef,
        Overwrite = true
};
uploadFile = _currentList.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileCreationInformation);
_currentContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

And file uploaded. But on server we have event that adds some random string to the file title. So fileRef is not relevant after upload.

And we need to set the Author of the file. For this we have to retrieve file and update this propery. I do it with this sample:

```
string fileName = serverRelativeURL + msg.Message.FileName;
uploadFile = _currentContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(fileName);
_currentContext.Load(uploadFile);
uploadFile.ListItemAllFields["Author"] = _currentUser;
uploadFile.ListItemAllFields["Editor"] = _currentUser;
uploadFile.ListItemAllFields.Update();
_currentContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

And on ExecuteQuery() I get an Exception "File not found". But if I copy path from Sharepoint (with that random string) everything works Ok.

So the question is: Is there other way to retrieve file? By id for example? because when we uploading file, instance "uploadFile" does not have much of useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:
Keep track of the filename, and then use this code to retrieve it directly.

```
    public FileInformation GetFileFromAttachment(int itemId, string filename)
    {
        FileInformation file = null;

        //continue here
        if (new FileInfo(filename).Name != null)
        {
            CSOMUtils.ExecuteInNewContext(QueryConfig.siteUrl, delegate(ClientContext clientContext)
            {
                clientContext.Credentials = QueryConfig.credentials;
                clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web, l => l.ServerRelativeUrl);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();


                List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(ListName);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                string url = string.Format("{0}/Lists/{1}/Attachments/{2}/{3}",
                    clientContext.Web.ServerRelativeUrl,
                    ListName,
                    itemId,
                    filename);

                var f = clientContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(url);
                clientContext.Load(f);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                file = File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, f.ServerRelativeUrl);


            });
        }
        return file;
    }
```

Method 2:

You can use ServerRelativeUrl to get the folder containing all the attachments. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.folder.serverrelativeurl.aspx
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/132008/reliably-get-attachments-for-list-item

Comment: You assume that you have itemId and filename. And when you do: "var f = clientContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(url);" filename is changed on server side. So filename is no more relevant. And when you do "clientContext.Load(f);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();" it will throw exception "File not found". Please read question carefully.

Comment: The code works when you supply it a filename, it's being used in production. As far as I know, you cannot download the file without the filename. Is the random string of a specific length, maybe you can trim it off.

Comment: I expected that after "var f = clientContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(url);". f will contain Id(or something like it) of the uploaded file and I can retrieve this file by Id (because filename are no more relevant).

Comment: The files are stored as attachments literally as they would be in directory in windows, but inside the content database, and in such a way you can even enable BLOB storage on them. I think you can get all the attachments and loop through them if you have the listitem id. But you need the filename to identify them. The files are not list items themselves, so AFAIK they do not have IDs. Why don't you try to keep track of the filename instead? Who cares if it's randomly generated... keep track of the randomly generated filename. If it can't be done the way you want to do it, it can't be done.